# Why does identifiers.org forward to addresses that do not contain linked data?

Tags: uri, rdf, semantic-web, linked-data

For example, if I want to link to a dbSNP identifier: rs936126, I link using identifiers.org to this URI: http://identifiers.org/dbsnp/rs936126, which then forwards me to this address: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/SNP/snp_ref.cgi?rs=rs936126.

This address is really bad 1990s-esque HTML, not a linked data/ machine readable language, from what I can tell. It seems like a mistake that identifiers.org doesn't forward to a URI that exposes the data in a linked data format?

Can someone help educate me about this issue? How does one go about finding the right URIs they can use as subjects -  or predicates for that matter - that describe and RESOLVE specific biological entities?

Note, I do NOT want ontology terms, which simply *define* what a given property/attribute name *means*. Rather, I want a document that describes a given and *specific* biological entity - say a specific variant, gene, genomic chromosome, etc.